# How to set onClickListener in Fragement

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I cannot figure out how to set an `onClickListener` in a `Fragment`.  I feel like I am missing something silly.  I know this works in a simple activity but I don't know why it doesn't work in a Fragment.  I am thinking I may need to pass something other than `this` to the `onClickListener()` method but if so, I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks to anyone looking at this!

```
 public class LogFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{


    Button logButton;


   public LogFragment() {

   }
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container, false);

     logButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.logButton);
     logButton.setOnClickListener(this);

       return rootView;  //Changed it to this and still doesn't work
     //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container, false);

   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {

      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You clicked it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onCreateView, you are supposed to return the view that you already inflated, not inflate another view (which doesn't have a click listener attached to its button).

Comment: If I follow you correctly, you are saying to return `rootView` but when I try that, it still doesn't work.

Comment: No worries.  I thought I was sure. It does work.  I have two buttons on the app and was clicking the wrong one.  What a bonehead move huh?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are returning a inline newly inflated view on the onCreateView method.

Instead of

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container, false);
```

try

```
return rootView;
```